Calculate RMS Power Density for patch antenna radar
I am using the RFbeam K-LC1a and I am trying to calculate the RMS Power Density for it based on the datasheet provided for the product. It specifies that the EIRP power output of the transmitter is +15 dBm which corresponds to about 31.6 mW. It also has a beam width of 80° and beam height of 34°. Given a distance, what is the power density assuming that the antenna is redirecting all output power within that window? Also, how would I calculate at what distance it would cross \$10 W/m^2\$?
I've tried the following, but this is for an ellipse, not a rectangle projected onto the surface of a sphere.
$$
r_h = r \cdot tan(\frac{θ_h}{2}) = 1 \cdot tan(\frac{80°}{2}) = 0.839 \\
r_v = r \cdot tan(\frac{θ_v}{2}) = 1 \cdot tan(\frac{30°}{2}) = 0.268 \\
A = \pi \cdot r_h \cdot r_v = \pi \cdot 0.839 \cdot 0.268 = 0.706 \\
PD = \frac{Pt}{A} = \frac{0.0316}{0.706} = 0.0448
$$
Giving me \$44.8 mW/m^2\$ as the power density at 1-meter distance if I modelled that correctly.
Update: My ultimate goal is to determine whether there is a danger to exposure of this 31.6 mW transmitter and whether there is a mandatory label requirement needed when close to it. This would be when the density crosses \$10 W/m^2\$ for a 24 GHz transmitter.

The antenna pattern broadside to the antenna IS an ellipse, not a rectangle.  Look at Figure 2 in the data sheet.

Why would your power density away from the antenna be greater than that at the face of the antenna?  The antenna is 1"x1" or 1 sq in.  This is 0.00064516 sq m.  The EIRP of 31.6 mW is measured, or calculated at this surface.  As you move away from the antenna surface, the power density falls off as 1/R^2.  So the power density at a distance where the surface 1 m^2 is going to be 31.6 mw*0.00064516, or 0.0204 mW, if I did my math correctly.

@SteveSh I believe that should be division for density (31.6 mW/0.00064516 m^2) = 48.98 mW/m^2, but the point that my model breaks down this close to the antenna seems to be correct as it is not a point source.

Your math is wrong - it should be 48.98 W, not mW.  But even that is incorrect.  While your power density, in W/m^2 is correct,  that really doesn't mean anything since your radiating aperture is only 1 in^2.  You don't magically get more power just by putting it in terms of W/m.  The only way to get more power in this example is to add more 1"x1" 31.6 mW radiating elements.  That is, increasing the size of the aperture.  This is exactly what happens with AESAs -Active Electronically Steered Arrays.

\$R=\sqrt{\dfrac{EIRP}{Ω⋅S}}=4.9cm\$​  will not be very accurate with a distance near the wavelength and antenna size for a 2D aperture from a 2D antenna within 10 wavelengths.
Solid Angle  Ω [steradians] = Horiz{rads]*Vert[rads]
EIRP   [Watts]
Power Density S  [W/m^2]
​
